# Iterating through a listview for specific ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I've got some labels in a listview, 2 per row. One contains a title, the other information. I want to change all the titles when the user presses a button that fires the ListViewSelectEventArgs. I think they have the same ID since they're from the ItemTemplate, so I thought that's how'd I target them. I'm just not sure how I'd step through the listview.

Here's my attempt:

```
int x = 1;
        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.lvSteps.Controls[0].Controls.Count; i++ )
            {
                if ( this.lvSteps.Controls[0].Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(Label) &&
                     ( this.lvSteps.Controls[0].Controls[i].ID == "lblStepNumber" ||
                       this.lvSteps.Controls[0].Controls[i].ID == "lblNewStepNumber" ) )
                {
                    Label lbl = this.lvSteps.Controls[0].Controls[i] as Label;
                    lbl.Text = "Step #" + x;
                    x++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your event handler for SelectedIndexChanging

```
lvSteps.Items(e.NewSelectedIndex).FindControl("lblStepNumber").Text = "whatever"
```